# Wrong time shown in catalina.out

Tags: java, ubuntu, tomcat7, catalina

Running in a Ubuntu 16.04, Tomcat7 and Java7_OpenJDK, I can see that in my `catalina.out` log, all events are shown with the incorrect time. The difference is -1 hour from what it is set on the system.

Trying to be sure that timezone is correctly set for java, I have tried to explicitly set the timezone in `setenv.sh` file, using `CATALINA_OPTS`, as follows:

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Duser.timezone=Europe/Madrid"
```

When I restart the tomcat service (by using `service tomcat7 restart`), if I make a

```
ps -aux | grep tomcat7
```

I can see that new tomcat7 process is running using the specified '-Duser.timezone'. 
But anything changes on my 'catalina.out'.

The strange thing, is that if I set in `setenv.sh`:

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Duser.timezone=America/Chicago"
```

After restarting the service, `catalina.out` is already showing the same -1 hour from my real time...

So, where is supposed that I have to set or change the timezone to be used by `catalina.out`?

Comment: Are you sure it's not just logging in UTC in general? (That would be a sensible log format, IMO...)

Comment: Hi Jon, I don't think so, because comparing with UTC, is logging in UTC +1.

Comment: Right, I suspected so, but thought it was worth a try. Sounds like it's getting its time zone setting from somewhere else then...